# AVD Cannot access to internet

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I'm from Iran, as you know Google has denied us to access to developer services, so we use Proxy to access them.

Now the problem is: When I use a proxy in Android Studio 3.2 limits Will be gone but AVD will not connect to internet but if I choose "No Proxy" my limits will comeback and AVD will connect to internet.

How can I use Proxy and have internet on AVD both at a same time?

I have no idea what I can do. I did not see any proxy or network connection settings when I created a new virtual device.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Finaly Solved the problem myself.

This is The solution for everyone who may have same problem:

Run emulator
and follow this steps :

[image: More]

More -> Settings -> Proxy

[image: Settings -> Proxy]

Then uncheck  "Use Android Studio HTTP proxy Settings" and Then check "No proxy"